# How to enable amdgpu-pro's VDPAU driver on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, amdgpu, vdpau

I have downloaded and installed `amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504.tar.xz` on Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit).

I have verified that the `libvdpau-amdgpu-pro` package is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l libvdpau-amdgpu-pro:amd64
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version               Architecture          Description
+++-=================================-=====================-=====================-========================================================================
ii  libvdpau-amdgpu-pro:amd64         1:17.0.1-465504       amd64                 AMDGPU Pro VDPAU driver
```

I have also created symlinks for the vdpau driver in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0.0 \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0.0
$ sudo ln -s /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0.0 \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0
$ sudo ln -s /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0.0 \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1
$ sudo ln -s /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so.1.0.0 \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_amdgpu.so
```

`vdpauinfo`, however, reveals that the incorrect driver is being used:

```
$ vdpauinfo
display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0
```

G3DVL is the "Generic GPU-Accelerated Video Decoding" library, which provides GPU-accelerated decoding only for MPEG-1/2 video.

How do I enable the VDPAU driver provided by amdgpu-pro?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions on http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx ?